# must $g(x)$ be zero almost everywhere and does $\int_{\alpha}^\beta g(x)dx = \lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \int_{\alpha}^\beta f_k (x)dx.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory, definite-integrals, contest-math

> 1. Let $g(x)$ be an integrable, real-valued function on $[a,b]$ and let $K\in\mathbb{R}$.  If for every $\alpha \leq \beta \in [a,b], \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} (g(x)-K) dx = 0,$ does it follow that $g(x)=K$ almost everywhere on $[a,b]$?

> 2. Let $f_k$ be a sequence of real-valued integrable functions on $[a,b]$ so that $f_k\to g$ pointwise. Prove or disprove that $\int_{\alpha}^\beta g(x)dx = \lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \int_{\alpha}^\beta f_k (x)dx.$

> Source: see the solution to problem 15 of the Bernoulli trials solution: [https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~x46wang/BernoulliTrial/BT2019soln.pdf](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ex46wang/BernoulliTrial/BT2019soln.pdf). If my claims are wrong, then I'd prefer answers to the corrected claims.

For problem 1, I was thinking of coming up with a contradiction, but $g(x)$ may change sign. If $g(x)$ always had the same sign, then $\int_a^b g(x)-K dx = 0$ implies $g(x)=K$ almost everywhere on $[a,b]$.

For problem 2, the Dominated convergence theorem requires the elements of the sequence $(f_k)$ to be "pointwise" bounded by an integrable function, though it doesn't seem like we must have that $|f_k(x)|\leq g(x)$ for all x. For instance, if $f_k(x)=(1+1/k)x$ for all x and $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and $g(x)=x$, then clearly $f_k(x)$ converges pointwise to $g(x)$ on $[a,b]$, but $f_k(x)$ is not pointwise bounded by $g$. By the definition of pointwise convergence, we can say that for all $x\in [a,b] \,\forall \epsilon > 0,$ there is some $K$ large enough so that $f_k(x) < g(x)+\epsilon$ for all $k\ge K$. It seems the claim would be true if $f_k\to g$ uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

An integrable function is almost surely continuous:
If the function is $f(x)> K$ at some point $x$ then it will be greater than $K$ for values in some interval starting at x - by continuity. This will then lead to a contradiction.

Comment: More formally, the set of points of discontinuity of a Riemann-integrable function is of measure zero, which is not obvious to prove, and so I didn't want to use this nontrivial fact. But even if $f(x) > K$ at some point x, can't $f(x) < K$ for other points?

Comment: Also, you haven't answered my second question. I asked two seemingly separate questions, but both questions arise from the solution to one calculus question.

Comment: @user33096 It’s well known that the second statement is false and as for the first question, yes it can be less than $K$ for some other points but we don’t care. We just pick $\alpha,\beta$ suitably so that the interval doesn’t contain any points where it is less than $K$